# Got error E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages. while installing Ruby on Rails

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies

Command used:

```
sudo apt-get install git-core curl zlib1g-dev build-essential libssl-dev libreadline-dev libyaml-dev libsqlite3-dev sqlite3 libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev python-software-properties libffi-dev
```

Output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
curl is already the newest version.
curl set to manually installed.
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
build-essential : Depends: g++ (>= 4:4.4.3) but it is not going to be installed
Depends: dpkg-dev (>= 1.13.5) but it is not going to be installed
libcurl4-openssl-dev : Depends: libcurl3 (= 7.35.0-1ubuntu2) but 7.35.0-1ubuntu2.5 is to be installed
Depends: libkrb5-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: libldap2-dev but it is not going to be installed
Depends: librtmp-dev but it is not going to be installed
libsqlite3-dev : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu2) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (= 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.15 is to be installed
Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not going to be installed
libxml2-dev : Depends: libxml2 (= 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4) but 2.9.1+dfsg1-3ubuntu4.4 is to be installed
sqlite3 : Depends: libsqlite3-0 (= 3.8.2-1ubuntu2) but 3.8.2-1ubuntu2.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

[image: Screen shoot]

How to solve this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, it will solve your dependency problem:

```
~$ sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge libsqlite3-0:amd64
~$ sudo dpkg --force-depends --purge libsqlite3-0:i386
~$ sudo apt-get update
~$ sudo apt-get install -f
~$ sudo dpkg --configure -a
```